# Diagnostic of a frozen screen? Fresh 17.10 Ubuntu install

Tags: 17.10, freeze

I'm having a semi-common occurrence of a frozen screen, with a still-responsive mouse. Any sound or music that was playing will continue to play while frozen. I've found a few resources on what to do when it happens, though I haven't had a chance to test them yet...

[One link with possible next steps after a freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

[Another link with possible next steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151049/how-to-deal-with-a-frozen-screen)

But I'm actually more interested in figuring out what's causing the freeze. I haven't seen any consistency from what's causing it on the surface, but maybe there's something in a log that I don't know about yet.

Any suggestions around logs to check just after a freeze, or some other report to diagnose the problem?